# ViewController with NavigationController loops to itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

To put it simply, I've built an app which started without a Navigation Controller so everything was controlled through my ViewController. Since adding the Navigation Controller, I added a button to flip to my main Navigation Controller window from my ViewController. However, when I push the button, it reloads the same window with the Navigation Bar now across the top(I hid it in the original view). If I push the same button again, it then loads the proper view.  What did I do wrong to cause this loop?

My button's code below

```
-(IBAction) btnSettings_Clicked: (id) sender    {
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip View" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
MyAppDelegate* appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:[self.navigationController view] cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[appDelegate.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is in ViewController and, as you say, this controller is not pushed on a navigation controller, then the error is:

```
[self.navigationController view] ;
```

because there are no navigation controller for self. You have to replace it with:

```
[appDelegate.navigationController view] ;
```

As I asume that is the correct navigation controller to use.

And then, why are you popping the top view controller? If you want to remove self.view, then you only have to do it:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is this line

```
[self.navigationController view]
```

You should set the animation to the controller you wish to show and not to the current controller.